# textToBePresentInElementValue waits even text is present and jasmine timesout

Tags: protractor

I have a situation where I wait for the element text to change from running to successful, but I can see when my test is running that even the text is shown as Successful its still waiting and then the jasmine timeout error occurs.

I am not sure how to fix this.
PropertyPage:

```
   this.reportList = element.all(by.repeater("report in reportList"));
   this.ReportStatus = this.reportList.all(by.css('div.display-inherit'));
```

Test Case:

```
   browser.wait(EC.textToBePresentInElementValue(PropertyPage.ReportStatus , 'Successful'));
```

Answer (score 2):

The difference between **textToBePresentInElement** and **textToBePresentInElementValue**

- the first is checking for the value of a text inside an element ('#abc')
- the second is checking for the input value of a text inside an element textfield ('#myInput')

I got the same error *Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null* when I used **textToBePresentInElementValue** to get the text of an element.

**[ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.textToBePresentInElement)**

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
// Waits for the element with id 'abc' to contain the text 'foo'.
browser.wait(EC.textToBePresentInElement($('#abc'), 'foo'), 5000);
```

**[ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementValue](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.textToBePresentInElementValue)**

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
// Waits for the element with id 'myInput' to contain the input 'foo'.
browser.wait(EC.textToBePresentInElementValue($('#myInput'), 'foo'), 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not setting variables before but the whole element inside the wait, does it force to get the value again ?

```
browser.wait(EC.textToBePresentInElementValue(element.all(by.repeater("report in reportList")).all(by.css('div.display-inherit')), 'Successful'));
```

Also, is your locator "div.display-inherit" looking for a single element div.display-inherit on the page? You have to be sure to locate the precise one to look into it. Could you get it with another locator?

Comment: `div.display-inherit` refers to multiple elements in ng-repeat but if I am using it `browser.wait(EC.textToBePresentInElementValue(ReportStatus.get(0) , 'Successful'));` its giving error   `Failed: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null`

Comment: Do you need to add the "this." to ReportStatus ?
And if you add the .get(0) to what I wrote, do you also get the indexOf null ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion in my question, I have updated the question. and if I use `browser.wait(EC.textToBePresentInElementValue(PropertyPage.ReportStatus.g‌​et(0) , 'Successful'));` I still get `Failed: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null`

Comment: If you don't use the PropertyPage and use directly the locator inside the PropertyPage, does it change anything? Just to know if it comes from the object or from the locator used.